# FlashBuilder 4.6 vs. FDT 5.5 Free vs. FlashDevelop 4.0  vs  IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ide

Dear Flex/Flash developers,

Considering you have to choose a new IDE for the next (at least) 3 years regarding flex web and AIR mobile development, what would you pick as the best option?

I am working for ~6 years with flex/flash builder but I can say I am sometimes unsatisfied about the amount of features and the performance that you get for a very expensive licence.

I started evaluating FDT and I find it great. Unfortunately I think that the premium version is still expensive and the free version which I am considering to use lacks a lot of "core" features (like for example - profiling).

Recently I got back to FlashDevelop by some random fact and found out that it looks much better then in the older versions (at least from the specifications side).

Now I am a little confuse and I would like to know, maybe you got recently to make the same decision, what was your pick and why ... ?

Looking forward to your answers and wish you happy programming !

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately I do not have too much experience with IntelliJ IDEA. But if you can give more details about why/how to use it, this would be great to know.

Comment: Yes U are right, I did forgot about it... I will edit my post.

Comment: I voted to close as this is not a programming question.  StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.  For profiling; you need to have Flash Builder (I think the premium version).  At some future point, Adobe Monocole should help such things, but the "sales" model for that is currently unknown.  A lot of programmers I know love IntelliJ.

Comment: You need the compiler that comes with Flex (now Flash Builder).The compiler is free, and you do not need to pay for a Flash Builder license. Flex was handed over to apache and is now open, you can get the compiler through http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/ or at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download-all.html

Comment: @Flextras, thanks for the comment. I know this is not a bug or a programming issue, but you see very often such kind of questions on this community website. Anyway I do know about the features of Flash builder, but which IDE are you using ? which one would you recommend to someone who will start learning flex development tomorrow ?

Comment: @Daniel, It is not about compiler or flex sdk, this question is in regard to an IDE to use on top of FLEX. I guess you are not using notepad to build your enterprise apps ??!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you answered your own question already. FlashBuilder is too expensive for what it does, and FDT is too expensive compared to FlashDevelop.

I would rule out FlashBuilder right away, and then ask if FDT is worth the extra $.

If you're on a pc, I don't really see a reason to chose anything but Flashdevelop. FD is developed actively, it is free, and and last time I checked (though it wasn't recently) it does about the same that FDT. The shortcuts that FD has are very helpful, if you're going from FlashBuilder, and essential when going from FDT.

I've been programming AS in FlashDevelop for a long time now, and they've added a lot of good features since, like the debug and profiler. and I have not needed to switch to any other environment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, indeed F.D. is free and open source and at this point it may be the best option out there. One thing which I find not so easy to achieve is migrating existing projects and somehow "habits" from flash-builder to flashdevelop. How is mobile development with FD ?

Comment: There are a lot of resources from the community, like sample project files that can help with that, for example this link shows how to compile for iOS - http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/build-an-app-for-iphone-or-ipad-with-flashdevelop/